# call-by-reference function parameters

Tags: python

Given a function:

```
def A(a, b, c):
    a *= 2
    b *= 4
    c *= 8
    return a+b+c
```

How can I set the 'c' var to be called-by-reference, so if i call `d = A(a,b,c)`, c will point to the same int object, and be updated from within the function?

Comment: you can't... Unless you make a mutable numeric type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting into murky territory: you're talking about declaring `global` (or `nonlocal`) variables in functions, which should simply not be done. Functions are meant to do one thing, and do them without the consent of other values or functions affecting their state or output.

It's difficult to suggest a working example: are you alright with having copies of the variables left behind for later reference? You could expand this code to pass back a `tuple`, and reference the members of the `tuple` if needed, or the sum:

```
>>> def A(a, b, c):
        return (a*2, b*4, c*8)

>>> d = A(2, 4, 8)
>>> sum(d)
84
>>> d[-1] #or whatever index you'd need...this may serve best as a constant
64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Python cannot do that.

What you *can* do is pass a wrapper that has `__imul__()` defined and an embedded `int`, and the augmented assignment will result in the embedded attribute being mutated instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if `c` is a list:

```
c = [2]
def A(a, b, c):
    a *= 2
    b *= 4
    c[0] *= 8
    return a+b+c[0]
print c  # gives [16]
```

Answer (score 1):

All calls in Python are "by reference". Integers are immutable in Python. You can't change them.

```
class C:
   def __init__(self, c):
       self.c = c
   def __call__(self, a, b):
       a *= 2
       b *= 4
       self.c *= 8
       return a + b + self.c
```

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/Dy9dy)

```
A = C(1)
print A(1, 1), A.c
print A(1, 1), A.c
```

#### Output

```
14 8
70 64
```